# configuration issues with perl on xampp

Tags: windows, perl, xampp

Am new to perl and its working under windows(using xampp 1.7.4 ).

Am trying to use perl to send email (using gmail smtp).The issue is that i seem to have successfully installed `Net-SMTP-SSL` with `ppm` so i was expecting it under `c:\\xampp\perl\bin` but it seems to have gone under 'c:\xampp\perl\site\lib'.
now when running my script i am getting this :

> Can't locate Net/SMTP/SSL.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/5.10/i686-cy
>   gwin /usr/lib/perl5/5.10 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10/i686-cygwin /usr/lib/perl
>   5/site_perl/5.10 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10/i686-cygwin /usr/lib/perl5/vend
>   or_perl/5.10 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 /usr/l
>   ib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 .) at getbalanceWindows.pl line 5.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at getbalanceWindows.pl line 5.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're running it under Cygwin.

Using ActiveState `ppm` will make it available to cmd.exe, not Cygwin.

A couple of options here:

1. Use cmd.exe
2. Install `Net::SMTP::SSL` via `cpan` to make it available to Cygwin

   ```
   $ cpan Net::SMTP::SSL
   ```

   or

   ```
   $ perl -MCPAN -e 'CPAN::Shell->install("Net::SMTP::SSL");'
   ```

#### Side Note

Does XAMPP necessitate the use of Cygwin? Methinks not, but I may be wrong.

Comment: i've actually installed cygwin separately after xampp for some experiment.ssh login (i prefer it to putty).So i got both.but i would prefer to stick to xampp to kinda have the windows perspective.thanks